# Sum of binomial coefficients multiplied by $k^2$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Show the method used to evaluate $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{12} {12\choose{k}}k^2$

The answer is $159744.$

Comment: @Soke I wrote a computer program to find the answer. :P

Comment: @Thomas do you mean the sum to be indexed with $k$, and $k$ going up to $n$ (instead of 12)?

Comment: Ok, there was a typo which I fixed. I changed i to k.

Answer (score 8):

\begin{align}
f(x)&=(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^k\\
f'(x)&=n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}kx^{k-1}\\
xf'(x)&=nx(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}kx^{k}\\
(xf'(x))'&=n(1+x)^{n-1}+(n-1)n(1+x)^{n-2}=\sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}k^2x^{k-1}\\
x&\leftarrow 1\\
\therefore \sum_{k=1}^n{n \choose k}k^2&=n2^{n-1}+(n-1)n2^{n-2}=n(n+1)2^{n-2}\\
\end{align}

Comment: For anyone else having a brain freeze understanding the last step (I stared at it way longer than I should) simply let $x=1$.

Comment: @IanMiller Sorry about that. I added it.

Comment: Thanks. I loved your answer but found myself scratching my head a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{12} {12 \choose k} k^2 = \sum_{k=2}^{12} {12 \choose k} k(k-1) + \sum_{k=1}^{12} {12 \choose k} k \\
= \sum_{k=2}^{12} \frac{12!}{(k-2)!(12-k)!} + \sum_{k=1}^{12} \frac{12!}{(k-1)!(12-k)!} \\
= \sum_{k=2}^{12} \frac{12!}{(k-2)!(10-(k-2))!} + \sum_{k=1}^{12} \frac{12!}{(k-1)!(11-(k-1))!} \\
= 12 \cdot 11 \sum_{k=2}^{12} {10 \choose k-2} + 12 \sum_{k=1}^{12} {11 \choose k-1}.$$

Can you finish from here? Note that this approach generalizes straightforwardly (albeit tediously) to any sum of the form $\sum_{k=0}^N {n \choose k} k^\ell$.