# Closed formula for the power series

Tags: closed-form

I have no clue how to attempt this problem.

consider the power series: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
Find the closed form formula for the function $f(x)$ to which the power series converges.

Comment: You need to use latex to typeset your maths text.. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) for the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-x)^n=\frac1{x+1}$$
$$\therefore f(x)=\int \frac1{x+1} dx=\ln (1+x)+C$$
$$f(0)=0 \rightarrow C=0$$

Comment: Ok, why does -x^n become 1/x+1?

Comment: Generally, try to make the series to something like $\sum x^n$ or $\sum (ax)^n$ ($a$ is a real number including $-1$ in this case). If it's in the form of $\sum nx^n$ then if you integrate it you can remove $n$. If it's in the form of $\sum \dfrac{x^n}n$ then if you differentiate then you can remove $n$ too. Sometimes it's more complex form like $\sum n^2x^n$ or $\sum \dfrac{x^n}{n^2}$ then you'll have to integrate or differentiate several times.

Comment: You probably need to multiply or divide by $x$ or $x^m$ $(m\in\mathbb N)$ to adjust $x$'s exponent. Take a look at this and you'll see how you should apply this strategy depending on situations. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566506/sum-of-binomial-coefficients-multiplied-by-k2/1566522#1566522

Comment: The above applies only to the form of $\sum (ax)^n=\frac1{1-ax}$. You can also remember Taylor series expansions of some famous functions like $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$ and then you'll be able to solve more problems like this kind.

Comment: Well, to answer to why $\sum (-x)^n = \frac1{x+1}$, let $S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n$. And then try to add these two series $S+xS$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

One way forward is to write for $-1<x\le 1$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^x u^n\,du\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^N(-u)^n\,du\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^x \left(\frac{1-(-u)^{N+1}}{1+u}\right)\,du\\\\
&=\log(1+x)-\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^x \left(\frac{(-u)^{N+1}}{1+u}\right)\,du \tag 1\\\\
&=\log(1+x)-\int_0^x\lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\frac{(-u)^{N+1}}{1+u}\right)\,du \tag 2\\\\
&=\log(1+x)
\end{align}$$

where the Dominated Convergence Theorem justifies going from $(1)$ to $(2)$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. Happy Holidays! - Mark